# Does Ubuntu reduce battery life?

Tags: ubuntu, laptop, battery

This questions is loosely related to **[Does dual boot harm a laptop battery or reduce its life?](https://superuser.com/questions/1465259/does-dual-boot-harm-a-laptop-battery-or-reduce-its-life/1465764?noredirect=1#comment2210399_1465764)**. In that question I have asked if **Dual boot** decreases battery life. Here I have asked, does **Ubuntu** decreases battery life.

Does Ubuntu decrease the life of the battery?

I dual-booted my laptop with Ubuntu 17.10 and Windows 10 one year back. After one year, my laptop battery backup has reduced to 40 minutes. The answer provided in the above link says dual boot does not harm the battery. Hence I suspect that it might be possible that Ubuntu decreases the life of the battery. I don't know, but I have experienced that Ubuntu drains the battery faster than Windows.

Comment: I think a more reasonable cause of batery degradation would be related to the fourth topic (Don’t leave your laptop on permanent charge) in this article: [link](https://www.techadvisor.co.uk/feature/laptop/how-improve-laptop-battery-life-3462609/).

Comment: I downvoted because you are ignoring what people write and repeat your question all over the place.

Comment: @nobody And I upvoted because the actual answer is a nuanced, and its valuable to the community! (I also disagree with both you and GabrielaGarcia - and Ive done a significant amount of testing and research here.)

Comment: @Nobody I am not repeating my question .That question was related to dual boot , here i am just asking about ubuntu  .If on that place would have edited my question after i accepted the answer then it would have been unfair .Also i am not asking this question just for self benefit since my battery is already dead.It will help others too .Also you can see the answer provided by davidgo is different from the answers provided on the link .Hence my question is bit different .

Comment: Using the battery decreases the battery life.

Comment: What is the normal life of a battery? 2-4 years? 40 minutes seems reasonable (you did not mention the total length of time).

Comment: @PeterMortensen 17.10

Comment: if you are so worried about battery wear then run your laptop on power save mode, unplug it at 80% and plug it at 30% for its entire life.

Comment: **Are you using the laptop differently when booted into Ubuntu then when booted into Windows?** If so, the things you think you observed is not happening.

Comment: What does *I dual-booted my laptop with Ubuntu 17.10 and Windows 10 one year back* mean? You either use Win or Ubuntu.... What are you comparing to what?

Comment: Also temperature reduces battery life, if you really want to preserve battery and extend its shelf life you should store it charged (how much charge depends on type) in cold place but not freezer...

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Without extra care, yes, although this can be mitigated/avoided, and the main cause is just wear and tear. The problem is not Linux per se, but the vendors' focus on Windows optimizations for battery life, and heavier power draw kills a battery faster.

The main things which degrade a rechargeable lithium-based battery are:

- Heavy discharge
- Full charge, particularly keeping full charge
- Number of charge/discharge cycles
- Heat
- Storing battery fully charged/Discharge
- Age - maximum capacity of a perfectly maintained battery still decreases with age.

Because Linux is heavier on the battery than Windows, the amount of heat is higher, causing faster wear. Similarly you likely have more charge/discharge cycles, because the battery is used more.

Some mitigations/trade-offs to improve battery -

1. If your BIOS supports it, set maximum charge to less the 80% (or even 70%) - shorter work time, much longer battery life in net terms.
2. Use `powertop` to reduce power draw.
3. If you are a road warrior, try charging when you are not using laptop to reduce heat. Likewise a slower charger will do less damage.

   3a. It seems discharging from 80-40% once is less stressful than discharging 80-60% twice.
4. Don't let your battery level fall below 20%
5. Try keep the laptop comfortably cool. Leaving it on in a backpack causes heat buildup.
6. Slow charging and/or using a larger battery causes less wear for a similar amount of usage, because it helps with the above.

(Where numbers are used above, they are indicative only.)

Comment: `Because Linux is heavier on battery then Windows`. Do you have any reference which proves this? I think there are tons of factors that get involved here, apart from the OS kernel itself..

Comment: @XtremeBiker there are indeed a ton of factors, and I am confident a well tuned Linux system can be tuned to perform similarly to a Windows system.  Have a look at https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/3mnnso/will_linux_ever_have_great_battery_life_on_laptops/ (I was at the LinuxConf event where this took place, and I run Linux on my laptops and desktop).  Importantly, no one tells you to run Powertop or TLP when you get a Linux laptop.  Windows comes preinstalled and tweeked so you don't need to.

Comment: Why would Linux be heavier on a battery then Windows ? In my personal experience, Laptop batteries have performed better - lasting longer - with Linux running, compared to Windows.

Comment: my laptop BIOS is set to stop charging at 90%, and start charging at <=80%, that battery has been holding up great since mid-2017 now :) (2019-07-31 as of writing)

Comment: @Robert Riedl: Linux keeps the CPU busy much more than Windows → higher internal temperature → higher battery temperature → lower battery lifetime (?). Also, if running primarily on battery (not the charger), the higher power consumption also increases the number of charge cycles, also lowering battery lifetime.

Comment: @PeterMortensen, but why would Linux keep the CPU busy ? Or rather: Why would it keep the CPU more busy than any other OS (BSD, Windows,..) ? I, as a Linux User, have made the opposite experience. But that's probably because I tinker with the OS a lot to try and get the best out of it. I bet someone else would have the same experience with their favourite OS... this `$other_OS is heavier on  battery then $my_favorite_OS` is probably highly biased...

Comment: @Robert Riedl: Not biased, this is just what I (and others - but they did not provide a solution) have observed (on a small nettop with dual boot). The exterior of the nettop is much warmer running Linux than when running Windows 7. I would be *very interested* in what you have done. E.g., do you have some *specific* references you can point to to solve this problem?

Comment: This was using stock versions of Ubuntu and Windows. The answer on *[Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/tour)* (I can't find the references right now, but I have them somewhere) was essentially that nothing could be done about it.

Comment: @PeterMortensen - oh god I did so much to my nettop... one special thing that comes to mind, is that I use the webcam as light sensor (since the nettop does not have one) to automatically adjust the background light. Also, regarding temperatures: Maybe under Linux the fans were not spinning as much ?

Comment: @PeterMortensen, there is a great amount of practical information on how to get better battery performance on Linux on [ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Power_management#Power_saving)

Comment: Usually the problem is *not* because Linux keeps the CPU working more than Windows -- it's pretty much everything else. Storage devices are kept online longer, wifi isn't optimized and so on. The CPU is the least sinful of all your devices.

Comment: or in other words, people care more about Windows battery life than Linux battery life, so Windows gets all the fixes and tweaks to make it use less power.

Answer (score 15):

Good answer by davidgo, and that should be your starting point for understanding and minimizing the issue.  But the wording of the question implies that you're thinking about this in a slightly wrong way, and I'll focus on that aspect.

You keep referring to Ubuntu "decreasing" battery life, and that's not really an appropriate way to look at it.  Say one OS is better than another at optimizing battery life.  If you use the better one as a baseline, the other OS won't be as good in that respect, so it kinda looks like battery life is "decreased" in relative terms.

But really, "batteries decrease battery life".  When batteries are a source of power, any battery is a disposable item.  Everything you do or don't do affects battery life a little.  davidgo's answer lists the major factors.

If one OS uses a little more power than another, that might lead to recharging more often.  So some factors can affect other factors.  But if you get the daily run time you need even with the OS that uses more power, you might recharge at the same frequency and from a discharge level that, for practical purposes, is in the same range.  So your usage pattern may be a bigger factor than the OS.

The point is that batteries have a finite life.  There are things you can do to optimize and extend the life a little.  To the extent it's practical to do those things, they can't hurt.  But finite battery life is a characteristic of operating from batteries.  In the scheme of things, a few months difference in battery life doesn't represent a big cost.  It doesn't make sense to let it drive important decisions.

Let's assume one OS is not as good as the other at optimizing battery life so it costs you a little more over time for battery replacement.  You own the computer because it is a tool to help you accomplish things important to you.  People spend extra money to get a keyboard or mouse that they can use more efficiently, or a high-resolution monitor so they can see more of their work at once.  The same applies to the OS.

You pick an OS because of what it allows you to do, and things like the user interface that make it easier for you to get your work done.  You don't pick it because one will save you a few dollars every couple of years on battery replacement.  For that matter, if you are comparing Windows and Ubuntu, Windows costs money and Ubuntu is free.  So if Windows saves you a few dollars on battery replacement, you haven't saved money, you paid for that in advance.

Ubuntu doesn't "reduce" battery life.  It might yield a slightly different life.  But as they say, "that's life".

Comment: You are right .My most of work is on Ubuntu and i like it .I will not remove it for saving few dollars :)

Answer (score 1):

No.

How fast the capacity of a battery drops over usage cycles is largely independent of the software running on the laptop. It mostly depends on amount of charge cycles, average relative charge amount, temperature, battery controller (which is not part of the operating system) and a bunch of other factors.

Comment: This is wrong because Typicsl Linux (but not Android) is way heavier on battery then Windows because vendors optimise for Windows and ignore Linux. This is well documented, and unsurprisingly the experience of the OP as stated.

Comment: No it's not wrong; 1) Linux isn't way heavier on battery than Windows.  If you have some piece of hardware where power savings aren't supported yet then yes; otherwise no.  2) draining the battery faster or slower before you charge it back up should not affect the lifetime of the battery.  Unfortunately, the main culprit for batteries that wear out that fast is fast charging, which the end user typically has no control over.  (I.e. if it took 8 hours to charge the battery instead of 1-2, the battery would last through many more charge cycles.)

Comment: @user153822 You should research before you make statements. 1. Power saving is nor a binary state of supported or not - its nuanced tradeoffs and design parameters. 2. The faster you drain the battery the more heat and faster it dies, also the more charge/discharge and/or greater discharge depth. 3.  At last something on which we do not totally disagree, although speed of charge is only 1 part of the picture, and partly  mitigated by slowing down as battery gets fuller.

Comment: @davidgo Power saving might not be binary, but the important part has like two or three bits which are suspend, hibernate and backlight and if those all work then Linux can easily be better than Windows. If those don't work, I don't know why you would willingly buy that laptop.

Comment: @nobody that is a gross (to the point of being incorrect) oversimplification. Skim through https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=SMKTgXIPCLA to hear a Linux expert on the nuances. (Also, hibernate/suspend dont define hiw long you can actually do work in a laptop)

Comment: @davidgo, power management, as illustrated by the link you shared, is basically just switching devices off and reducing performance/frequency as much as possible, with as little impact for the user as possible - which works great under Linux AFAIK.

Comment: _"... Linux ... is way heavier on battery then Windows ... This is well documented, ..."_ - If it's well-documented, can you provide sources? (I watched the video you linked in a later comment; it does provide some nice insights in the nuances and complications of power management, but there's nothing in there comparing OSses.)

Comment: @marcelm Lots of places https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/power-batterywindows.html.en  - also  see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ByVdH92YrCU (4:17 vs 2:44 for same conditions).  It is interesting though that as time has progressed, the situation has improved drastically -  If you look at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119606/why-does-linux-have-poor-battery-life-by-default-compared-to-windows this was accepted as fact - but I can now find plenty of anecdotes with Linux being faster then Windows, so times they are achanging!

Comment: @RobertRiedl My new laptop's battery life doubled (4 hours -> 8 hours) when I installed bumblebee. That's because now, the GPU is switched off when it's not needed. Previously, it was unused, but still powered up. Who knows how many *other* bits of hardware my laptop has that are like that? Windows knows, because HP tested their laptop with Windows. Linux didn't until I happened to install the right bit of software.

Comment: @user20574, that is kind of my point. For every OS you have to install the right software tools, spend some time in the settings... compare it with your GPU: If you install a plain Windows, you GPU might perform decent - maybe better than in a plain Ubuntu. But once you install the right software and drivers in Windows and Linux, performance should be on par on both.

Comment: @RobertRiedl Your laptop *comes* with those tools on Windows. On Linux, you might not even know you *have* the piece of hardware in question. Or that it has the power-saving modes in question.

Comment: @user20574 - no it doesn't. A plain Windows install is functional, mostly, but needs additional drivers. Especially with notebooks you need to install the software/drivers from the manufacturer.

Comment: @RobertRiedl When was the last time you used Windows? nVidia definitely installs its own drivers as part of Windows Update, for example. In notebooks, drivers are usually preinstalled (part of the vendors partition). Manually installing any drivers is quite rare nowadays.

Comment: @Luaan, I have to use Windows as my office device. You expect every Laptop to be pre-installed ?? That is not standard. I think its better to assume a basic install. Currently and for the past years, we have been using HP Elitebooks. Every driver, from chipset to docking station, has to be installed from the HP homepage or via the HP software package installer. Almost nothing comes from windows update. Sure you have basic functionality initally, but that's it.

Comment: @RobertRiedel and yet the HP Elitebooks my place of work insisted on had all the drivers and a LOT of extra HP crap to boot straight out the box. Im with Luaan on this one.If it.comes.with Windows 10 it most likely ships with drivers - its a lot easier to package drivers.with the install then provide helpdesk to acquire them.

Comment: @davidgo, I guess we are then comparing apples and oranges ? I guess you could have a look at Dell's line of laptops, that come preinstalled with Linux. They probably perform better than an initial install as well. Also, I just read the links ... the Wiki entry seems very old ( *[..]If your computer has a variable speed processor[...]*) as is the question on unix.stackexchange. There have been leaps and bounds on Linux driver integration, because the AAA manufacturers have (currently) warmed to Linux and open-source. There is no documented problem with energy management in the last years.

Answer (score 0):

@davidgo , well the machines i've had got much *better* battery life in ubuntu than windows (especially with 4.18 kernel or newer.). I just didn't want to sound like some fanboi .  Linux currently has a design that allows for more time in low power mode, and typical linux distro has fewer background scans and junk than windows allowing for lower power usage.  But then if some driver (especially video driver) doesn't support going into low power mode then power use is nice and high.  It pretty much *is* a binary state in these cases, like a gpu that starts up at 700mhz but supports 150mhz (but the driver doesn't) or (in the distant past) when a sata or usb controller wouldn't support the low power states on the ports (like almost turned off but can still detect when something is plugged in to power it back up.)